# Problems with writing results to the data.frame (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 5 names of points (column “from”) and their coordinates (columns “cx”, “cy”) in the data.frame.
I would like to compute the distances from the point "i" to the point "j", then save name of point (column "to") which is nearest to the current point. My data and code are below.

```
> df
       from        cx        cy   color category
1  path3389 125.71429 366.64792 #000000        2
2  path3391 220.00000 529.50507 #000000        2
3  path3393 437.14285 632.36218 #000000        2
4  path3395 534.28571 472.36221 #000000        2
5  path3397 602.85712 243.79079 #000080        3
6  path3399 297.14285  69.50506 #008000        1
```

Sorry for the such presentation of my data.
Code is below:

```
# sort by 5th colonm = category, 
# where 1 - start point, 2 - middile, and 3 - finish point
df <- df[ order(df[,5]), ]
n <- 5
for (i in 1 : n){
rr <- 1000000000
#----------------
for (j in i+1 : n){#nrow(df)) {
     sqrt = ((df$cx[i] - df$cx[j])^2 + 
             (df$cy[i] - df$cy[j])^2 )^(1/2);
     if (sqrt < rr) {
          rr <- sqrt
          tmp <- j
     print(rr); print(j)
        } 
}# forj
df$to[i] <- df$from[tmp] # error is here?
} # fori
```

The result is

```
[1] 343.0476
[1] 2
[1] 188.1814
[1] 3
[1] 240.2719
[1] 4
[1] 187.181
[1] 5
[1] 238.6356
[1] 6
```

Here **343.0476** is minimum distance between 1st (path3399) and 2nd (path3389) points, i.e. I should take element (**path3389**) from the column "from" and write to the first row of column "to".
Here **188.1814** is minimum distance between 2nd (path3389) and 3rd (path3391) points, i.e. I should take element (**path3391**) from the column "from" and write to the second row of column "to".

Expected result is

```
> df
       from        cx        cy   category  to
6  path3399 297.14285  69.50506        1  path3389 
1  path3389 125.71429 366.64792        2  path3391
2  path3391 220.00000 529.50507        2  path3393
3  path3393 437.14285 632.36218        2  path3395
4  path3395 534.28571 472.36221        2  path3397
5  path3397 602.85712 243.79079        3  # empty
```

But now I see:

```
       from        cx        cy   color category to
6  path3399 297.14285  69.50506 #008000        1  1
1  path3389 125.71429 366.64792 #000000        2  2
2  path3391 220.00000 529.50507 #000000        2  3
3  path3393 437.14285 632.36218 #000000        2  4
4  path3395 534.28571 472.36221 #000000        2  5
5  path3397 602.85712 243.79079 #000080        3  1
```

Could someone please say me how to write command `df$to[i] <- df$from[tmp]`
in the code? I have check the first column of df:

```
> df$from[tmp]
[1] path3397
5 Levels: path3389 path3391 path3393 path3395 path3397
> df$from[1]
[1] path3399
5 Levels: path3389 path3391 path3393 path3395 path3397
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have it in your result but do you want to capture the actual distance ?  Also, can you provide a sample of input data that will help troubleshoot, you can use `dput` and paste the result in the post.

Comment: Your variable `from` is a factor, as you can see from the "Levels". So, if you're trying to get the values of this variable step by step, at every iteration, you will get numbers and not the actual values. That's how the factor variable is used in R. Try to also use `as.character` in each iteration.

Comment: @AntoniosK, thanks it's work: df$to[i] <- as.character(df$from[tmp])